# Where is the `EventLog` log located?

Tags: c#, event-log, error-logging

Where is the [`EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) log located ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view event logs with the Windows [Event Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer). The actual logs are in the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Config` directory with an `.evt` extension, according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/70328/where-how-does-windows-store-the-data-in-the-event-logs) on ServerFault.